# OS X app in Swift without XIB

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, swift, nswindow

Has anyone figured out a way to bootstrap an NSWindow-based app without using a XIB (or IB at all)? In iOS, this is fairly simple;

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

        window!.rootViewController = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        return true
    }
```

But I just can't get it to work right for a desktop app.. NSWindow doesn't have a makeKeyAndVisible() method, and NSApplicationDelegate seems to have a dozen overrides for func application().. What's the magic incantation?

Comment: makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil) it is what you are looking for

Comment: How come you have accepted the answer, but didn't upvote?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    let newWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: NSScreen.mainScreen()!.frame, styleMask: NSBorderlessWindowMask, backing: NSBackingStoreType.Buffered, defer: false)
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        newWindow.opaque = false
        newWindow.movableByWindowBackground = true
        newWindow.backgroundColor = NSColor.whiteColor()
        newWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }
    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't get it -- this requires a main menu xib for me still

Comment: Leo, Copying this answer into identical questions is really poor style.

Comment: Useless. You still need MainMenu.xib for this.

Comment: Can you please unaccept this answer so I can delete it?